# Unable to post Notification from AppDelegate upon handling localNotification action

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

In my app delegate I am trying setup the LocalNotification ActionHandler to perform a segue and send a notification to the destination ViewController to trigger a function in that class, but somewhere along the line the notification isn't being posted or received properly.

It's worth noting that the destination view controller has not being innitatited at this point.

**Here is my code currently:** 
Snippet from AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {


    if identifier == "mainAction" {

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        (self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first?.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NC_SegueDidPerform", object: nil)    
}
```

and here is in the receiving View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("NC_SegueDidPerform", object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: ({ (notification: NSNotification!)  in

        print ("working")
    }))
}
```

I tried putting the observer in a ViewWillApear and ViewDidAppear as well, but to no avail. The block simply does not get executed!

How do I make it work so that I can receive a notification (or any kind of 'signal' in the destination View Controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: I clarified my question. How do I achieve receiving a notification in the target view controller?

Comment: `performSegue` is not immediate, so you are sending the notification before it has completed. As you pop all controllers before the segue, you have no observer controllers, unless I am missing something? The only controllers are the root of the navigation controller and the destination controller of the segue. You would be better to just tell the destination controller it was pushed as a result of an action via the prepareForSegue method of the root controller.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to post notification.  Just bring up the destination VC and tell it directly what you want it to do for this local notification that you just received.

Comment: I want to be able to send data via userInfo, which is why I was hoping to get the Notification bit working as the destination view controller is dependant on data. So what you are saying is that i should call a 'prepareForSegue' method in order to access the target VC's variables?

Comment: Add a method to your root controller called `handleMainAction`, which takes your `userInfo` as an argument. In that method call `performSegue` and you can pass the `userInfo` in `prepareForSegue` to the destination controller. I can't see a need for notifications when you know who the one and only observer is. So IMHO, just use methods as described at the start of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way. As you rightly pointed out calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:` does not guarantee view controller to be available immediately so your notification that you fire the very next line does not reach the targeted view controller. The suggested Apple way is to implement `prepareForSegue:` and pass data to destination VC. This method is the opportunity for callee to pass any desired data to destination VC.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
   if (segue.identifier == "Segue") {
    // pass data to next view
   }
}
```

Comment: I did try this, but it doesn't work if I put it in the AppDelegate it seems. Should this be called from the rootViewController?

Comment: Implement this in your source VC, the VC from where your segue is getting started. If this is a new VC altogether then you would need to initialise it from storyboard and pass the data directly to the instantiated object.